# Why is Job referred to by the feminine pronoun in Job 1:15?

Tags: hebrew, grammar, job

טו  וַתִּפֹּל שְׁבָא וַתִּקָּחֵם, וְאֶת-הַנְּעָרִים הִכּוּ לְפִי-חָרֶב; וָאִמָּלְטָה רַק-אֲנִי לְבַדִּי, לְהַגִּיד לָךְ.

This verse, Job 1:15, ends with "and I alone escaped to tell you".  The "you" in Hebrew is in the feminine form, indicating that it is a woman to whom the servant escaped to give the message.  While Job is quite obviously not a woman: why is the feminine pronoun used to refer to Job here and several other places in this chapter?

Comment: I really do not understand the voting system on this site. How can you write something totally misguided (see the two answers) and still get rewarded 7 points?

Comment: @fdb I'm not sure I understand you correctly.  Are you asking why a question to which the asker does not know the answer, should be appreciated?  Or are you saying that I shouldn't have asked a question about a text I misunderstood?  As for the voting system: A question is not voted up because it correctly understands a text or has all the answers.  This question was voted up because it is a relevant question, and because it is worth publicizing so others with the same question can learn from the excellent answers.

Comment: If you ask: “Is the moon made of green cheese?”, we can answer the question and say “No”. If you ask: “Why is the moon made of green cheese?” then we need to say that you are misguided.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

That's not feminine; that's masculine. These are "pausal forms", so when the preposition *lamed* plus 2 msc sg suffix would normally be *lĕkā*, in "pause" it is *lāk* -- which is the same form as the 2 fem sg, and thus the confusion.

See Gesenius-Kautzsch-Cowley, *[Gesenius' Hebrew Grammar](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Gesenius'_Hebrew_Grammar/29._The_Tone,_its_Changes_and_the_Pause#GHGpar-29-n)*  (2nd edn; Clarendon Press, 1910), [at § 29n, p. 97](https://archive.org/stream/geseniushebrewgr00geseuoft#page/97/mode/1up) (last line of that paragraph).

Most grammars will give you a section on pausal forms (check index). There's a nice article by E.J. Revell, "[Pausal Forms in Biblical Hebrew: Their Function, Origin and Significance](http://jss.oxfordjournals.org/content/25/2.toc)", *Journal of Semitic Studies* 25 (1980): 165-179 [first article listed in ToC] if you're interested to dig deeper...

...or, even deeper, Richard Goerwitz's 1993 University of Chicago PhD dissertation, "[Tiberian Hebrew Pausal Forms](http://goerwitz.name/papers/dissertation/)". See also the Jewish Encyclopedia article on "[Accents in Hebrew](http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/11213-munah#anchor2)" for the interaction of the accentual system with pausal forms (or, with encoding problems at that site, see the [original page scans](https://archive.org/stream/jewishencycloped01newy#page/150/mode/1up)).

Answer (score 8):

It's not a feminine pronoun (although it looks like one)! *Lakh* (לָךְ) in this case is a form of the male pronoun *lekha* known as "pausal," which because of its position as the final word of the verse. Pausal forms generally expand a shva or e-vowel into a qamatz; for example, at the end of Genesis 1:1 *eretz* becomes *aretz*. See for example the chart [here](http://books.google.ca/books?id=dQudZ_1JDUkC&pg=PA168), or the examples of pausal *lakh* discussed [here](http://books.google.ca/books?id=82PbbAuQsfIC&pg=PA77) or [here](http://books.google.ca/books?id=vpDfWZUZ2W4C&pg=PA267).